# Runtime directive for List<Nullable<T>>

Tags: c#, generics, win-universal-app, .net-native

I'm getting a `MissingMetadataException` in the Release build of a Windows 10 Universal Application for a `System.Collections.Generic.List<Nullable<System.Int32>>` and can't figure out how to apply the runtime directive.

I've successfully added a directive for the simpler case, `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>`, which looks like this:

```
<TypeInstantiation Name="System.Collections.Generic.List" Arguments="System.Int32" Dynamic="Required Public" />
```

but I can't seem to correctly define the directive for the nested generic.  I've tried quite a few variations, mostly along the lines of the following:

```
 <TypeInstantiation Name="System.Collections.Generic.List" Arguments="System.Nullable" Dynamic="Required Public"  >
   <TypeInstantiation Name="System.Nullable" Arguments="System.Int32" Dynamic="Required Public" />
 </TypeInstantiation>
```

What's the correct way to handle nested generic types here?

Comment: I'd also be interested in seeing what's causing us to trip up as I would naively expect most of this to "just work". We do a ton of work in the .NET Native compiler to discover common reflection patterns so being able to see what you've written that confuses the compiler can help us write better analysis for everyone!

Comment: I was expected this to "just work" too :).  This is a library (there are actually 4 assemblies) which is released as a commercial product.  We make very heavy use of reflection, as well as the DataContractSerializer and a custom rellection-based serializer.  The assemblies currently have minimal rd.xml files and are built in Release mode.  The problem is occurring when testing an app which uses these libraries.  The app is in Debug mode with .NET native enabled, but the error message and stack trace are still not that helpful.  ... see part 2 below ...

Comment: .. part 2 ... I think the error occurs when we feed in known types to a custom DCS which is injected as an operation behavior in the WCF stack.  Among the known types required by our library are various List<T> and List<Nullable<T>> where T is a numeric type or other structure.  We do a typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t) here, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: Seems like something we may be able to make progress on in the compiler. I'd be happy to chat with you via email to get some more specifics so that we can see what can be done. If that's something you'd be able to help us out with, the email address to get us is dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions. If you enable .NET Native for DEBUG (project properties > BUILD > checkbox for Enable .NET Native) you'll get a much better overall debugging experience. In particular, you'll get more helpful messages from your exceptions as the DEBUG configuration saves the resource strings needed to make a nice error dialog. I suspect it'll point you to this page http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html which should help get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen the troubleshooter before but had gotten hung up on the TypeInstantiation directive at some point.  The troubleshooter did help fix the metadata problem.